# Where can I download a template sql database with data already entered?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Where can I download a template sql database with data already entered?

I am learning how to use sql so I want to play around with a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx